# How much rice cakes is too much with regards to arsenic toxicity?

Tags: toxicity, arsenic

Lately there's talk of rice having arsenic and I do eat rice cakes every day and  do not want to stop. I eat every day between 1-3 oz. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. According to consumer reports it's too much. Got to find a replacement :-(

http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine/2015/01/how-much-arsenic-is-in-your-rice/index.htm

Comment: There is no need to delete the question. The next person with a similar question can have a look at your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely do not delete.

I was ready to dismiss consumer reports out of hand, but level of analysis  suggests question of arsenic exposure not trivial.

Thanks for posting report link.